# Get nearby cities in Geonames Android

Tags: android, geonames

Hi I am making an application in which I am supposed to find out all the cities which are nearby a specific lat-long location.

Now my radius is 30km.

I am using the Geoname public webservice given at :

http://www.geonames.org/

I am currently using the following url

http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyJSON?username=xxxx&country=US&lat=38.8951118&lng=-77.0363658&radius=100&formatted=true&featureCode=PPL&featureClass=P

But this query returns all the populated places near a lat-long, not cities, so I am getting neighborhoods, schools etc in response. I just need the cities.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL should be something like this:

> http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?username=xxxx&country=US&lat=38.8951118&lng=-77.0363658&radius=100&formatted=true&featureCode=PPL&featureClass=P

Check this [link](http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html#citiesJSON) for more details.